# Change color of theme with Android viewpager transition

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

how can i change the color of theme smoothly with viewpager transition like this ,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [`OnPageChangeListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) on the `ViewPager`. Th `onPageSelected()` callback will tell you when a page has been set as the current page (either by scrolling manually or by setting the page programmatically). Then you can change the background color of the app bar based on the selected page.

Comment: only if it was that easy. :3